# How to send and receive XML file through Serial port /dev/ttyS0 in python

Tags: python, serial, sockets

It seems I am able to send text file (.txt file) through serial port but it is not working with .XML file. Can anyone help me here. Might be I m missing something from decoding part.

**Client SIDE:**

```
import serial
s=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',9600)

while (1):
   s.write(open('test.xml',rb).read())
```

**Server Side:**

```
import serial
serial_port = '/dev/ttyS0';
baud_rate = 9600; #In arduino, Serial.begin(baud_rate)
write_to_file_path = "output.xml";

while 1:
    output_file = open(write_to_file_path, "ab");
    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate)
    line = ser.readline()
    output_file.write(line)
    print(line)
    output_file.flush()

output_file.close()
```

Comment: And what is the Raspberry Pi Question? This look like a programming question! And please use the formatting features!

Comment: This may sit better on the programming sites as its software rather than a Pi.  Saying that, I think your issue is that the XML file will not have any end of line markers (newline for Python).  Its not needed within XML (and some parsers ignore them) - only handy for us humans.  Look at the file with `hexdump` to check then read the file byte by byte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872381/how-to-read-a-file-byte-by-byte-in-python-and-how-to-print-a-bytelist-as-a-binar NOTE: you also need to work out how to tell the receiver that the file is complete.  May send length first or binary EOF